# Как узнать тип диска в KVM?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Есть три типа диска - LVM, Raw и QCOW2. Как узнать, какой из типов сейчас установлен на моей VPS в Ubuntu 16.04?

Comment: Эммм... узнать в поддержке хостера?

Comment: Попробуйте запустить команду "vgscan". Если её нет - LVM у Вас не установлен. Про остальные - не знаю.

Comment: @Sergey после ввода `vgscan` появилось сообщение `Reading all physical volumes.  This may take a while...` и почти сразу всё закончилось и я снова мог вводить команды в консоль.

Comment: @JamesJGoodwin Ну значит, LVM у Вас установлен. Но, похоже, не настроен...